# public_path() in Laravel 4.2 wrong on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-4

My app (Laravel 4.2) is currently run on heroku

When i call public_path() in my controller. I got "/app".

But if i call in development (osx with php artisan serve). I got "/public"

How can i fix this i want "/public" instead of "app"

This is my paths.php

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

I use https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php as a buildpack url

Comment: Change the line to `'public' => (\App::environment() == 'local')? __DIR__.'/../public' :  <Path/To/Your/Public/Directory/On/Your/Live/Site>` I cannot fill this in for you as you failed to show what folder structure your live site has etc.

Comment: I got PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in paths.php

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm running into the same problem in Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you use

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

as your `Procfile` command to configure `public/` as the document root?