# Laravel helpers return wrong paths on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

Laravel paths helpers return wrong paths by adding `app` at the beggining of every path, like this is a directory here but isn't.

E.g. `{{ resource_path('testing') }}` returns `/app/resources/testing`. While it should return `/resources/testing`.

I do not have any `app` directory up to `resources` directory. It's standard almost fresh laravel application.

I did also `web vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`. But still this problem occurs.

I found a few people have this problem, like here [public_path() in Laravel 4.2 wrong on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744777/public-path-in-laravel-4-2-wrong-on-heroku)

But couldn't find any answer to this.

Currently I use this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I never had problem like this and it is really strange for me.

I think it is related to heroku.